# Oracle - single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a query which I'm trying to get it working on oracle but get the following error

SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

The query is:

```
UPDATE TARGET A
SET A.COL1=(SELECT B.COL1 FROM SOURCE B) 
WHERE A.COL2=(SELECT B.COL2 FROM SOURCE B)
```

Basically, I am trying to update only those records which match in the join.

I'd be extremely grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement needs to be a correlated update-- you need some key in `A` that tells you which row in `B` to go to in order to retrieve the new `COL1` value.  Your `WHERE` clause should also be an `IN` or an `EXISTS` since it needs to return multiple rows.  Assuming `COL2` is the key (based on your `WHERE` clause), I'm guessing that you want

```
UPDATE target a
   SET a.col1 = (SELECT b.col1
                   FROM source b
                  WHERE a.col2 = b.col2)
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM source b
                WHERE a.col2 = b.col2 )
```

If that is not what you're looking for, posting some table definitions, sample data, and the expected output would be quite helpful.